# Highcharts sankey. Highlight all paths of a given category

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In the default Highcharts Sankey diagram, you can hover over individual paths and the paths are highlighted.

I want to be able to hover on the node - for example Canada in the example below - and have all the red paths highlight while hovering on that node.

To clarify, I still want to be able to hover on them individually, but when I hover on the leftmost box (the darker red piece), I want all red paths highlighted.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burchw78/fgjap25w/)

```
series: [{
    keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
    data: [
        ['Brazil', 'Portugal', 5 ],
        ['Brazil', 'France', 1 ],
        ['Brazil', 'Spain', 1 ],
        ['Brazil', 'England', 1 ],
        ['Canada', 'Portugal', 1 ],
        ['Canada', 'France', 5 ],
        ['Canada', 'England', 1 ],
        ['Mexico', 'Portugal', 1 ],
        ['Mexico', 'France', 1 ],
        ['Mexico', 'Spain', 5 ],
        ['Mexico', 'England', 1 ],
        ['USA', 'Portugal', 1 ],
        ['USA', 'France', 1 ],
        ['USA', 'Spain', 1 ],
        ['USA', 'England', 5 ],

    ],
    type: 'sankey',
    name: 'Sankey demo series'
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this **live demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/v79mb8eo/

I created function that changes the state of all link points that start in the given node:

```
function linksHover(point, state) {
  if (point.isNode) {
    point.linksFrom.forEach(function(l) {
      l.setState(state);
    });
  }
}
```

It's executed on point's `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events:

```
  plotOptions: {
    sankey: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: function() {
            linksHover(this, 'hover');
          },
          mouseOut: function() {
            linksHover(this, '');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#setState
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOut

Comment: Excellent. I made a quick adjustment so this also works if you hover on the nodes on the right side. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/burchw78/94qqs7oa/)

Answer (score 0):

```
// you can do more like ...
// sankey chart node disable path hightcharts

 series: [
        {
          point: {
            events: {
              click: async function (e) {

                if (this.shapeType == "path") {     <-- add this 
                  return;                           <--
                }                                   <--
```